# (error) ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:2: '=' expected near 'local'

Tags: lua, redis

Within my Redis cache I've run

```
SET 12345 JoeDude
SET JoeDude "It works!!"
```

I've a Lua script that is intended to be run from the terminal:

```
lua
local user=redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
local output=redis.call('GET', user)
return output
```

At the terminal I run `redis-cli --eval lua_R_and_D.lua 12345`

I then receive the following error: `(error) ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:2: '=' expected near 'local'`

What, pray tell, am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the word `lua` before your first actual statement. Maybe comment that out?

Comment: That was it!
I had seen various web pages that started with "lua", but when running this now it returns the data as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out `lua` as in: `--lua`
Not too familiar with lua as a language but apparently it is good for server side scripting and -- is the comment for the lua language.